# Generating decimal values in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, decimal

How to generate a vector of lets say 5 decimal values such that their sum is 10.

```
for i=1:5
   d(i)=rand;
end
```

1)I know this generates the vector, but how to include the condition?
2) can I generate negative numbers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 d = rand(5,1);
 d = d * 10 / sum(d);
```